# $q.when not a function?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a simple application that has a main list with detail views, but I can't get past this error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794       TypeError: $q.when is not a function
at Object.getAllObjects (app.services.js:13)
at app.controller.js:11
at ionic.bundle.js:56230
at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:2140)
at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:56223)
at new MainController (app.controller.js:7)
at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:18010)
at $controller (ionic.bundle.js:23412)
at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:59900)
at Object.render (ionic.bundle.js:57893)
```

The code it is referring to is:

```
app.factory('DatabaseService', ['$q', '$http','$rootScope',

function DatabaseService( $rootScope, $q, $http) {  
var _db;    


var _content;

return {
    initDB: initDB,
    getAllObjects: function getAllObjects() {  
if (!_content) {
   return $q.when(_db.allDocs({ include_docs: true}))
        .then(function(docs) {


            _content= docs.rows.map(function(row) {

                return row.doc;
            });


            _db.changes({ live: true, since: 'now', include_docs: true})
               .on('change', onDatabaseChange);

            return _content;
        });
} else {

    return $q.when(_content);
}
},
getObject: function getObject(id){
  var index = findIndex(($rootScope._content),id);
  return $rootScope._content[index];
}

};
```

It seems as if all the dependencies are correct, so why am I getting this strange error? It seems that most of my recent errors have been "not a function" errors but I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed your injection :

```
['$q', '$http','$rootScope',function DatabaseService( 
  $rootScope, $q, $http) {  ...}
```

So in fact your $q contains $http, reorder this and it will work.

Comment: Thanks! Such an easy fix